# Spurious Illegal pair returned when converting array to Dictionary

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to convert an array of values into a dictionary with the key equal to the col name and the value as the col number. Code I have come up with is:

```
function myFunction() {

  var headers = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:1").getValues();
  var dict={};

  headers[0].filter(function(x,i){return dict[x] = i;}); 

}
```

The code works fine but I always get a spurious pair of `":num` where num is the last column number in the range, and it appears in the middle of the dictionary. Here is a sample sheet with the script:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JkhB_k3Fs4M_55BfqG3GERJqtxA44Hk0ERV-UpSbdeo/edit?usp=sharing

Its not the end of the world but I'd love to get rid of it if anyone knows how

Thanks

Comment: `if(x) return dict[...`

Comment: @dandavis - thanks. that's got it. Funnily I was using that in an earlier iteration to get rid of the blanks cells but it seemed like it was working without. Any idea why the other blanks cells weren't getting added in?

Comment: I couldn't open your shared Spreadsheet. Can you confirm it again?